# Build Failed -- AppService.h file is not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, ionic-framework, ios8-extension

I have already written Share Extension for ios. I have setup new Project where i am using  same share Extension. I copied and paste the entire code and directory.

Do i need to include header in x-code. how to setup headers in that case.

Now,  When i am trying to Build the project. it is giving me error .

```
**AppServices.h file is no found.**
```

Do i need to change any settings in X-code

Thanks

Comment: Header files need to be included in the Build Settings *Header Search Path*.  Have you checked that is the case?

Comment: Import your AppServices header file in `ProjectName-Bridging_Header`.h

Comment: @trojanfoe: i dont know. when i am trying to build  it is giving me error. Lexical or Preprocessor issue. AppServicers.h file not found,